# 2016 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Programming Puzzles & Code Golf's [first moderator election](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the 4 new moderators are:

[image: Martin Büttner] [image: Dennis] [image: Doorknob] [image: Alex A.]

Please thank them for volunteering!

And please join me in thanking Chris Jester-Young, dmckee and gnibbler for their [service as moderators *pro tempore*](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220/moderator-pro-tem-announcement). Level-headed moderation goes a long way toward making a site successful. Nowhere is that more important than on a site, such as this one, that breaks the mold of what we sometimes think of as "typical Q&A". I, for one, hope to see these folks remain leaders in practice even if they lack the title "Moderator".

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/election/1), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/6497348721049600/0).

Comment: "new" - I don't think this outcome surprises anybody :P

Comment: Thanks everyone! Looking forward to a fantastic fully-graduated site with the wonderful community that it has always had—you (yes, all of you!) are what makes PPCG, PPCG :)

Comment: [My reaction to the "new" moderators](http://i.steppic.com/a/6/1/6/a616f3e297bacd862a0c28f9ebf9e91d/0.png) :D

Comment: @Doorknob Congratulations, from a friend from Puzzling.SE ^_^

Answer (score 30):

Congratulations to our pro-tem moderators for being (re-)elected! You guys have done a great job moderating PPCG, and are all very good choices for our first set of formally-elected moderators. I look forward to seeing the site continue to improve with these 4 as moderators.

Thanks to gnibbler, dmckee and Chris for sacrificing their time and sanity to be pro-tem moderators during the long beta. Without them, this site wouldn't be what it is today.

Comment: +1 for 'sacrificing sanity'

Answer (score 30):

## Thank you so much, everyone!

And very special thanks to:

- **Chris Jester-Young**, **gnibbler**, and **dmckee** for their invaluable contributions to the site, particularly in its formative years. We wouldn't be here without their hard work and dedication.
- *Everyone* who voted at any point during the election. We had over 500 voters, which I'm told is quite a lot for a first time election.
- **Grace Note**, for getting the graduation gears turning.
- **Jon Ericson**, for this announcement, and for being supportive as we inched toward graduation.
- **Pops**, for greasin' the graduation wheels.
- **Martin**, **Doorknob**, and **Dennis**, for too much to say here.
- You, the community, for making this site possible.

Together we've built something amazing and I'm absolutely honored and thrilled to have been elected to continue to serve this community as a moderator.

Now back to flag handling!

Comment: Should pass those thanks to Pops as well - as much a factor in helping the graduation all move forward.

Comment: @GraceNote Pops!!! He's been added. :)

Comment: And thank you, Alex.

Comment: @isaacg :) I very sincerely mean it when I say it's my pleasure.

Answer (score 24):

Thank you to everybody here! I really enjoyed my last 5 years here, and I'm so glad that PPCG has finally graduated! Our site is in excellent hands, and I look forward to seeing what the dream team will do going forward. :-D

Comment: I'm so, so glad to have been able to learn from you. You're an inspiration, both as a moderator and as an all-around awesome dude. I know you're going to do great things with your business!

Comment: I've already expressed this far better in the 20th than I can in a comment, but it's been a fantastic privilege to have been able to be a moderator alongside you. See you around, and best wishes! :)

Answer (score 24):

**Congrats to @AlexA. @MartinBüttner @Doorknob and @Dennis !!!**

Really it was a forgone conclusion that you guys won and I am very happy with this result - our community remains in the hands of 4 excellent moderators.

Thanks to **all** the candidates, all of which I think put in really strong nominations.

Thanks as well to all the voters for taking part (especially those that voted for me ;-))!

I'm honoured to be part of this community as it demonstrated fairness, professionalism and enthusiasm through this election process - I think we're an even stronger community for having gone through it!

Comment: Hoping to see you again next time around :)

Comment: @Doorknob Thanks!